# the differentials are the same up to an endomorphism

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors, differential-forms

The generalized Gauss map $G:M^{n}\rightarrow G_{n,m}$ of a given immersion $f:M^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ assigns to each point $x \in M^{n}$ the point $f_{*}(T_{x}M)$ in the Grassmannian of $n$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.

My question is: If $f,g:M^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ are immersions with the same generalized Gauss map, then there exists $\Phi \in \Gamma(\mbox{End}(TM))$ such that $$g_{*}=f_{*}\circ \Phi.$$

Thanks for your hint or answer.

Comment: Hint: Consider $\pi\circ f_*$ and $\pi\circ g_*$, where $\pi$ is the orthogonal projection into $f_*(TM)=g_*(TM)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: For I obtain the conclusion It, should I use the uniqueness universal property for tensor product?

Comment: I don't see how tensor products are involved. Once you've shown that $\pi\circ g_*=\pi\circ f_*\circ\Phi$ for some $\Phi:TM\to TM$, then you can compose with the inclusion map $\iota:f_*(TM)\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and use the fact that $\iota\circ\pi\circ f_*=f_*$ and $\iota\circ\pi\circ g_*=g_*$.